# How to parse HTML for minification in PHP?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, html-parsing

I'm looking to write an algorithm to compress HTML output for a CMS I'm writing in PHP, written with the CodeIgniter framework.

I was thinking of trying to remove whitespace between any angle brackets, except the  `<script>`, `<pre>`, and `<style>` elements, and simply ignoring those elements for simplicity. I should clarify that this is whitespace between consecutive tags, with no text between them.

How should I go about parsing the HTML to find the whitespace I want to remove?

Edit:
To start off, I want to remove all tab characters that are not in `<pre>` tags. This can be done with regex, I'm sure, but what are the alternatives?

Comment: How do you deal with elements having a CSS declaration of [`white-space: pre`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/white-space)?

Comment: That wasn't really a concern of mine, as I wasn't aware that existed, and `<pre>` tags are valid in strict doctypes.

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/optimizing-html/

Comment: I like to think my markup is pretty clean: http://cms.timshomepage.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there something wrong with the existing HTML minification solutions?

[Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) does [HTML](http://code.google.com/p/minify/source/browse/trunk/min/lib/Minify/HTML.php) (as well as CSS and JS).

(That second link goes to the source code, which comments the steps it takes - should be a good leg up if you did want to create your own - it's [BSD licensed](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php).)

Also, as [Pete says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150531/how-to-parse-html-for-minification-in-php/3150606#3150606), you'll benefit *much* more by using gzip compression for your HTML (and CSS/JS/etc), and wont get tripped up by problems such as Gordon mentioned in his comment.

Comment: I'd forgotten than Minify worked with HTML. I already use it for JS and CSS minification. 

Also, I'm curious if it can be done without so many regular expressions. I was under the impression that regex was rather inefficient.

Comment: The problem with RegEx is less efficiency and more than HTML is not a Regular language, so cannot be correctly parsed with regex. You could investigate PHP's HTML DOM parsing (http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and consider writing something that used that and then just output again without whitespace.

Answer (score 7):

Don't.  Whitespace is negligible.  Better to be using output compression, [with zlib](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zlib.php) or [here for example](http://www.phpspeed.com/php-benchmark-f5/php-output-compression-t6.html)

Comment: I already output with compression, and am curious to see if I can minify HTML successfully.

Comment: The effort doesn't justify the savings, and it will potentially cause problems at some point, such as that Gordon has mentioned.

Comment: I realize it probably isn't worth the effort, but I was trying to do it for the challenge.